# Find solutions of a Log function

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $Log(1 −\sqrt3i)$.

This is the first question I encountered when I start the complex analysis exercises, 
These are the things what I did: 
1) Let $z = 1 - \sqrt3 i$
2) Compare the coefficients since $z=x+iy$
$x = 1$ 
 
$y = -\sqrt3i+2k\pi$

It seems that I am going in the wrong direction, could someone tell me what is the right way to do this?

Secondly, I wanna know about the difference between $Log$ and $\log$ (The block letter difference), are the basically the same or have special meaning behind?

Thank you.

Comment: According to me there is no difference between $Log$ and $\log$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another, not unrelated, but more fundamental approach:

Let $z=x+i y = \log{(1-i \sqrt{3})}$.  Then

$$e^z = e^x \cos{y} + i e^x \sin{y} = 1-i \sqrt{3} $$

Then $e^x = \sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{3}^2} = 2$ and $\tan{y} = -\sqrt{3}$.  From this, one may conclude that $x=\log{2}$ and $y=-\pi/3 + 2 \pi k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint:

Use Euler's formula which is $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$

$$\log(1-\sqrt3i)=\log\left(2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)\right)=\log\left(2e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}\right)$$

Comment: Good answer @PrasunBiswas

Comment: @Rememberme, Thanks. :)